# *ngFor not updating view after I push into array using papa.parse

Tags: angular, ngfor

```js
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Papa } from 'ngx-papaparse';
import {Model} from "./model";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  papa : Papa;
  file : File;
  options  = {
    data: [],
    complete :   function(results, file){
       for(var i = 0; i < results.data.length; i++){
          this.data.push(results.data[i]);
       }
       console.log(this.data);
      }
    }
 

onUpload(event){
  this.file = event.target.files[0];
  this.papa.parse(this.file, this.options);
}

  
  
  constructor() {
     
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.papa = new Papa();
  }
  

}
```

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onUpload($event)"(emitter)="emitted($event)">

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Franchise</th>
        <th>Starting ELR</th>
        <th>1st Month ELR</th>
        <th>2nd Month ELR</th>
        <th>3rd Month ELR</th>
        <th>ELR Increase Average</th>
        <th>Difference</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>DOMESTIC</td>
            <td>123.29</td>
            <td>128.62</td>
            <td>129.57</td>
            <td>129.86</td>
            <td>129.42</td>
            <td>6.13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor = "let data of options.data">
            <td>{{data[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[2]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[3]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[4]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[5]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[6]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have an input tag that takes an csv file. After the file is uploaded, i use papa.parse to convert it into json. I then push it all into an array. In my html i use the ngFor directive to output a table row for each array thats returned from papa.parse. However, for some reason angular *ngFor is not updating the view to reflect the added data. I know that the data is in the array because i have no problem logging it in the console. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The scope of this probably changes inside your papa object when it calls complete, use an arrow function so you don't change the scope of this

```
complete: (results, file) => { this.data = [...results]; }
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks!. Could you please explain what the problem was in more detail? It was logging fine to the console, so it was def being pushed to the data :[]. So why didn't angular update the view to reflect that?

Comment: this is a bit of a strange beast in JavaScript, this references the object that the function called from, not the object it was declared on. Arrow functions are always bound to the object they are declared in. Go read up on this binding in JavaScript and arrow functions.